# Do you have any ideas why text selection highlighting does not disappear in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a problem with text selection highlighting in textarea. It works properly when I, for example, select and deselect text using the mouse. The blue selection disappears as it should. However, the problem comes when I have a scenario as shown in the image. In the beginning, we have the text as in the first line. Then in the next step shown in the second line, I select the part of the text that I want for example delete or replace. And in the third line, I delete it using “delete” button. As you can see the upper part of the blue highlighted selection does not disappear. When I select this part one more using the mouse and deselect using mouse everything disappears. The same scenario is when I select the text using a mouse and I just start writing new letters. Then still the upper part of the selection is visible. Any ideas what is wrong and how can I solve this?

```html
  <textarea [readonly]="this.UserService.switchButton" type="text" class="no-style" #modelInput
            [(ngModel)]="this.UploaderService.inputText"
            style="position: absolute; top: 35vh; width: 50vw; left: 0vw; right: 50vw; height: 65vh; cols: 60; rows: 8;
       border-width: 0.1vw; overflow-y: scroll; resize: none; overflow-x: scroll; outline: none; background-color: white; border-color: black; color:black;"
  ></textarea>
```

[image]

Comment: you have a double cote no appropriate I don't know if is an error in the question or also in your code please check, when you close cote [(ngModel)]="this.Uploader Service.inputText"

Comment: @OAH I pasted the code from the project. Is it ok now?